# Negative number of parameters in hierarchical bayesian model

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, deviance, hierarchical-bayesian

I'm using Deviance information criterion to assess the fitness in my Bayesian hierarchical model.
The functional form of this criterion is as follows: 
$$DIC=p_{D}+\bar{D}$$
where $p_{D}=\bar{D(\theta)}+D(\bar{\theta})$ is effective number of parameters and $D(\theta)=-2log(p(y|\theta))$, $p(y|\theta)$ is sampling distribution and $\theta$ are unknown parameters.
And the problem is that the effective number of parameters when I use expectation as an estimes of $\theta$ is negative, however if I plug in a medians as estimates of parameters - $p_{D}$ is positive. I know that negative $p_{D}$ indicates prior-data conflict in non-log-concave distributions, but the the visual inspection of the fitted values indicates very good fit.
So, is it ok to use median as paramete estimates instead of expectations in DIC?

Comment: The use of medians instead of expectations does not invalidate DIC and its interpretation. My questions is more about is it Ok to use median estimates instead of expectations after I observed that $p_{D}$ are negative under expectations as estimates?

Comment: I see your point. In [the original paper](http://www.biostat.umn.edu/~brad/DICpaper_SBCVdL02.pdf) the authors say `However, we note that it is not strictly necessary to use the posterior mean as an estimator of either ... and the mode or median could be justified (Section 2.6).` ... `The median estimator leads to a pD, that is intermediate between those derived from the canonical and mean parameterizations.`

Comment: My opinion is that it is justified to use this version of the DIC, but it would also be desirable to strengthen the conclusions with the use of Bayes factors and perhaps BIC.